# Cron Job not working after Joomla 3.8.1 update

Tags: joomla, cron-job

After upgrading Joomla to 3.8.1 the cron job stopped working as reported [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20492/issues-with-running-joomla-3-8-and-civi). I have applied the update the Joomla.php file as suggested in the [answers](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/20802/4248). This gets rid of the original error. However now I am getting this error:

    `PHP Notice:  Constant JPATH_ISWIN already defined in /home/fava/public_html/libraries/import.legacy.php on line 64
    Notice: Constant JPATH_ISWIN already defined in /home/fava/public_html/libraries/import.legacy.php on line 64
    PHP Notice:  Constant JPATH_ISMAC already defined in /home/fava/public_html/libraries/import.legacy.php on line 65
    Notice: Constant JPATH_ISMAC already defined in /home/fava/public_html/libraries/import.legacy.php on line 65
    PHP Notice:  Constant JROUTER_MODE_RAW already defined in /home/fava/public_html/libraries/import.legacy.php on line 72
    Notice: Constant JROUTER_MODE_RAW already defined in /home/fava/public_html/libraries/import.legacy.php on line 72
    PHP Notice:  Constant JROUTER_MODE_SEF already defined in /home/fava/public_html/libraries/import.legacy.php on line 79
    Notice: Constant JROUTER_MODE_SEF already defined in /home/fava/public_html/libraries/import.legacy.php on line 79
    PHP Notice:  Constant JROUTER_MODE_RAW already defined in /home/fava/public_html/libraries/import.php on line 60
    Notice: Constant JROUTER_MODE_RAW already defined in /home/fava/public_html/libraries/import.php on line 60
    PHP Notice:  Constant JROUTER_MODE_SEF already defined in /home/fava/public_html/libraries/import.php on line 67
    Notice: Constant JROUTER_MODE_SEF already defined in /home/fava/public_html/libraries/import.php on line 67
    Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by "/home/fava/public_html/libraries/import.legacy.php" at line 64.`

I have tried manually clearing the Joomla session table but no luck.
I have also update CiviCRM to 4.7.27 and applied the patches as mentioned [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/21166/4248%20here) but the same error is still occurring.

Comment: I've just tested this again and I'm not convinced that the patch for CRM-21203 works for cron jobs that call `cron.php`, only `cli.php`. Your output looks as though you are using cron.php; as a workaround you could try having the cron job execute `php /path/to/civicrm/bin/cli.php -s site -u user -p password -e Job -a execute`
Note: I am also getting the PHP notices for constant already defined but they do not stop the job running via cli.php.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I am getting the errors using cli.php so I decided to change to cron.php and the cron job is now executing, not all the the jobs are running properly but atleast the we are starting to get somewhere

Comment: I should mention that for me even using cli.php there are still Notices, but the scheduled jobs run properl. But with cli.php I don't the Application Instantiation Error at the end - I only get that with cron.php.

Comment: I think there are still problems on CiviCRM 4.7.28. I've added to the existing issue [here](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21203?focusedCommentId=111804&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-111804)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated Joomla to 3.8.5 and updated CiviCRM to 4.7.31 (I'm using PHP version 5.6.34.) and the CRON job **still** didn't work.

I found and applied this [patch](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11609) and it worked. Thank you to [Andrew Thompson](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/users/2194/andrew-thompson) for your work on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like import.legacy.php is re-definining existing constants (or called twice)

I'm not familiar with Joomla, but can you try to remove requiring this file in civi (comment out line 565 in that file)

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Utils/System/Joomla.php#L565

Comment: There are still some problems in CRM/Utils/System/Joomla.php. When I was looking at CRM-21203 I did notice that CiviCRM should not be requiring both of Joomla's `import.php` and `import.legacy.php` as the content of [import.php](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/import.php) is really a subset of [import.legacy.php](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/import.legacy.php)
But there is still something else that stops cron.php working.