# Cron error with Joomla 3.8.1 and civiCRM 4.7.25

Tags: joomla, error, cron

I've found a cron error's in my Joomla 3.8.1 and CiviCRM 4.7.25 installation.
When i try to run my cron I see this error:

"PHP Notice: Constant JROUTER_MODE_RAW already defined in /Volumes/web/default/crmstore.washdog.it/libraries/import.php on line 60
 PHP Notice: Constant JROUTER_MODE_SEF already defined in /Volumes/web/default/crmstore.washdog.it/libraries/import.php on line 67
"
and cron doesn't work.

I've been tried to apply this patch https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11062/files?diff=unified , but unfortunally nothing change for me!

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this answer https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/21178/cron-job-not-working-after-joomla-3-8-1-update can help?

Comment: I think there are still problems on CiviCRM 4.7.28. I've added to the existing issue [here](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21203?focusedCommentId=111804&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-111804)