# Compatibility problem with Joomla 3.8.7 and Civicrm 5.0.1 that affects Cron

Tags: joomla, cron, civicrm.settings.php, compatiblity, version

On my last question [How to setup Cron in Civicrm- local server](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/24804/how-to-setup-cron-in-civicrm-local-server) I found out Joomla.php is having problem. i used curl or cli to run cron both does not work, here are the errors:

initial error
`require(C:\Apache24\htdocs\joomla\administrator\components\com_civicrm\civicrm\administrator\includes\defines.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Apache24\htdocs\joomla\administrator\components\com_civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Utils\System\Joomla.php on line 559`

after changing joomla.php and civicrm.settings.php civicrm_root slashes
`require_once(\libraries/import.legacy.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\joomla\administrator\includes\framework.php on line 15`

applied patch [Cron Job not working after Joomla 3.8.1 update](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/21178/cron-job-not-working-after-joomla-3-8-1-update/21179#21179) 
`require_once(\libraries/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Apache24\htdocs\joomla\administrator\includes\framework.php on line 18`

just wonder if there is a solution for this.

Comment: Just to note that for CiviCRM, both Joomla and Windows have relatively small usage so Joomla on Windows is very much a minority combination.  If your intention is to help debug and improve CiviCRM in that setup, that's great - but if your interest is to use it 'for real' then you can make life easier for yourself by using a more tried and tested combination.

Comment: Expanding on Aidan's comment, if you need to use a machine that is natively running Windows, consider using a virtualization program, e.g. VirtualBox, to run Linux on top of Windows.

Comment: Thank you Aidan, I'm intend to use it for real, and the pc I used is an old desktop with win7 (low budget purpose), I would consider to downgrade my Joomla to fit everything else. Thank you Bobs, but I'm not gonna use VirtualBox as it might complicate the setups and I want to keep the server simple and secure

Comment: For an old desktop, unless you really want win7, I'd put a Linux on it (maybe Ubuntu server or Lubuntu if you want a desktop as well) and keep Joomla updated.  Alternatively some of the hosting options start quite cheaply and include backups, standby servers etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are still likely to run into problems on Windows as Aidan mentioned but to give yourself the best chance:

- use CiviCRM 5.1.0, which has additional changes to resolve cli.php problems on Joomla 3.8
- use cli.php not cron.php. cron.php still doesn't work in some environments

My recollection of PHP and Apache on Windows is that paths with `/` work fine so you don't need to replace with `\` if that's what you meant when you said you changed civicrm_root slashes.

As you saw in the initial error, the path `C:\Apache24\htdocs\joomla\administrator\components\com_civicrm\civicrm\administrator\includes\defines.php` is incorrect. It should be looking in `C:\Apache24\htdocs\joomla\administrator\includes\defines.php`.

In `CRM\Utils\System\Joomla.php`, look in `getBasePath()`, around line 532, for this line:

```
$joomlaPath = explode('/administrator', $civicrm_root);
```

My guess is that the forward slash is not being matched in the Windows path so try changing it to:

```
$joomlaPath = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'administrator', $civicrm_root);
```

---

UPDATE 22 August 2018: The above change to `getBasePath()` [will be in CiviCRM 5.6](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12692)

Comment: Thank you Andrew your solution works! i upgrade the civicrm to 5.1.1, change the line 532 in joomla.php to"$joomlaPath = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'administrator', $civicrm_root);" and go to defines.php, change the path of libraries on line 20 to  "define('JPATH_LIBRARIES',     'C:\Apache24\htdocs\joomla' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'libraries');", run with cli.php (yes cron does not work the error is "Warning : ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time") AND IT RUNS! Thank you so much again!

Comment: Great, thanks for confirming Jennifer. The ini_set() warning is the problem that I'm aware of with cron.php.
I think it's worth getting that change to Joomla.php into core. Would you be able to file a bug report in Gitlab and if possible create a pull request on Github with that change to Joomla.php. If not I'd be happy to do it.

Comment: I don't have a account on Gitlab, you may file it if it's convenient for you